# What part of Facebook's interface code is responsible for changing the background color of the logo when hovering?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, frontend

I want to create my own skin for facebook and for that I have to take over control over what color does the logo's background change to when hovered. I've been looking for a line of code responsible for that behavior long and hard, but with no luck... Please help me find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple as that:

```
#pageLogo a:hover, #pageLogo a:focus, #pageLogo a:active {
    background-color: #4B67A1;
}
```

Comment: That's right, thank you! I was only using Chrome's developer console, I shoul've came up with simply looking into css :P